# Capture who all have accessed shared folders in last week?

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

In Windows Server 2012 is there a way that you can retrieve logs (via Powershell) of those who accessed, modified or deleted shared folders in the last week?

Answer (score 10):

Not unless [auditing was enabled](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/apply-a-basic-audit-policy-on-a-file-or-folder) before you wanted to run the report. If auditing is not turned on, then there's not much you can do.

If auditing was enabled, then you would need to parse the [Windows Event Log](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1) (via Powershell) for the appropriate events